# Visual Studio Attaching the 'IntelliTrace Debug Engine'

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just need to know about this error.
[image]

UPDATE: I fixed it by reinstalling the VS. By the way, I got the error when I tried to install VS update 5. While installing, it keeps looking for missing packages so I decided not to continue installing it. So when I restarted the studio and opened a project, the error was there.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and the errors you get with your attempts. Please also read this page to learn how to write a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the links below as it might help you sort the issue:

[Error: Unable to Start Debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or this one:

[Diagnosing ‘The debugger is not properly installed’](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/greggm/2004/04/16/diagnosing-the-debugger-is-not-properly-installed/)

Let me know how it went!